# JPA -Hibernate tuorial: Explicit persistence provider error-Could not create Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to learn JPA- Hibernate with a very simple example mentioned at this site
https://schuchert.wikispaces.com/JPA+Tutorial+1+-+Getting+Started
(I have tried alternate links as well but all ended up with same problem)

Before I describe my example in brief here I have listed the important exceptions-

```
Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "examplePersistenceUnit" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence from provider: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Could not create Configuration.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

configuration of project is as follows
persistence.xml {inside src folder directory META-INF}

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="examplePersistenceUnit" 
                      transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">     
       <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />

            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" 
                      value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" 
                      value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mem:aname" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                      value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and then I have a simple junit class which does the following

```
@Before
    public void init(){
         BasicConfigurator.configure();
            Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.TRACE);
        emf= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("examplePersistenceUnit");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

    }
```

Can any one please help me in resolving this I tried to search on forums and debugged it with decompiler but is of no use

Full exception trace

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Explicit persistence provider error(s) occurred for "examplePersistenceUnit" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence from provider: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createPersistenceException(Persistence.java:244)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:186)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:72)
    at entity.PersonTest.init(PersonTest.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: examplePersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:890)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:57)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:152)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error applying BeanValidation relational constraints
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.integrate(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:303)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1750)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:905)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationIntegrator.applyRelationalConstraints(BeanValidationIntegrator.java:208)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to build the default ValidatorFactory
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:524)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.applyDDL(TypeSafeActivator.java:119)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: javax.validation.ValidationException: Could not create Configuration.
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:175)
    at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.TypeSafeActivator.getValidatorFactory(TypeSafeActivator.java:521)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:571)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:349)
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:173)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Hibernate validator in your classpath?

If you are using Maven, just add the [dependency](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator) for the respective Hibernate version ().

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked I am still wondering how to debug these kind of issues. How did you get to this conclusion?

Comment: It's a common thing to overlook when starting with JPA. We've all been there :)